# Rails model validation failing and it shouldn't

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, validates-uniqueness-of

I have the following on my model:

validates_uniqueness_of :woeid

before_create :handle_woeid_issue

```
def handle_woeid_issue
    Rails.logger.info 'DID ENTER HERE'  #never enters here for some reason
    self.woeid = self.temp_woeid
  end

def self.create_if_not_existing(woeid)
    unless Location.find_by_woeid(woeid)
      Rails.logger.info '>>>> ' + Location.find_by_woeid(woeid).inspect #THIS OUTPUTS NIL
      gp = Place.find_by_woeid(woeid)
      Location.from_place(gp)
    end
  end

def self.from_place(gp)
    raise "Invalid argument " if geoplanet_place.nil?
    attrs = gp.attributes.dup
    attrs['temp_woeid'] = attrs['woeid']
    Rails.logger.info '>>>>>>>>>>>>> ' + Location.where(:woeid => attrs['woeid']).inspect #STILL NIL
    location = self.create!(attrs)
    location
  end
```

If the whole thing starts from

> Location.create_if_not_existing(woeid)

and it is being NIL (so no other record have the same woeid) WHY IT IS GIVING ME:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Woeid has already been
>   taken)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the order of execution during the insertion of an ActiveRecord object:

```
(-) save
(-) valid
(1) before_validation
(-) validate            *** BOOM
(2) after_validation
(3) before_save         *** too late
(4) before_create
(-) create
(5) after_create
(6) after_save
(7) after_commit
```

This means the validation is indeed run before your callback is called. To prevent this issue, you can use `before_validation` instead of `before_create`

Source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: temp_woeid is a copy of the actual woeid value. However you can see that the handle_woeid_issue is never called somehow. So how can that be the issue?

Comment: @content01 you were right, although I have another suspicion. Check out my edit.

Comment: The edit makes sense. However, it seems that `Place` has a `woeid` field too. When they do `gp.attributes.dup`, the `Place` object's `woeid` is in that hash. They never remove it, so it should be present for validation when they `create!`. I'm not sure if the callback is ultimately the problem.

Comment: Using before_validation instead of before_create actually fixed my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `before_save` or `before_vaidate` callback instead of `before_create` and try